# Does an abbreviation which is written in lowercase have to be capitalised after a period?

Tags: punctuation, british-english, abbreviations

I must use after a period an abbreviation which is "mtDNA" (mitochondrial DNA). It is always abbreviated with the two first letters in lowercase. I'm struggling to find a rule to know whether the "m" has to be capitalised or not after a period. For example would you write :

lorem ipsum. MtDNA is very important for cells.
lorem ipsum. mtDNA is very important for cells.

It appears to me more natural to have it lowercase also because I'm used to read it almost everyday.

Is there a rule that can be applied?

Best ,

Comment: Perfectly. Thanks I couldn't find my way to it. Thank you very much.